# Installing gems tries to load the gems in my custom rake tasks before installing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm developing an application using rails 2.3.5, gitorious and deploy with vlad, the OS is Linux Mint 9 Isadora.
vlad:setup and vlad:update are ok.
But when I `vlad:migrate` and have the same error than if I ssh on the server and try a rake gems:install

> rake aborted!
>   no such file to load -- ya2yaml
>   /var/www/path/to/releases/20100622030150/Rakefile:10
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

My `config/environment.rb` is good:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION  
# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration  
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')  
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|  
  config.gem "haml"
```

I have a custom task in `lib/tasks/db_fixtures.rake` that requires `ya2yaml`:

```
namespace :export do
desc 'Create YAML test fixtures from data in an existing database.
Defaults to development database.  Set RAILS_ENV to override.'
require 'rubygems'
require 'ya2yaml'
task :fixtures => [:environment] do
```

When I rename this file it is not loaded by rake and I don't have the error anymore when I `rake gems:install`

So my guess is that it looks like **rake gems:install tries to load the libs in my custom tasks before installing the gems** for some reason and throw me an error.

What would be a solution?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work? delay the requires on your rake task by moving them into the task itself

```
task :fixtures => [:environment] do
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'ya2yaml'
    # ...
```

by default running rake tasks 'loads' all of the rake files

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.
Delaying the requires fixed the problem.
Thank you.